# como se puede mostrar un texto rtf en react

Tags: reactjs, input, read, rtf

Tengo un par de archivos en formato rtf, que deseo importar dento de un imput text,

en php no tiene mucha dificultad **"file('TOS_Register.rtf')"** y asunto olvido pero en react me tiene un poco preocupado. no tengo idea de como hacerlo y lo que es peor busque en la red pero solo encuentro editores y nada mas.
claro que si necesitara editarlo estaría genial pero ahora solo quiero mostrar el contenido y ya.
ayúdenme por favor.

**editado el 15 de febrero de 2024**

no encontré la solución para visualizar la parte textual de un archivo rtf, no obstante transforme el documento a un pdf y lo mostré en un modal usando

```
import { PDFObject }                            from 'react-pdfobject'
<PDFObject url={url.donde.se.almacena.el.pdf} />
```

es necesario instalarlo para poder utilizarlo.

```
npm install react-pdfobject
```